# Dynamically update config in ASP.NET Core 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an application running on .NET 5. We have a configuration file which looks like this

```
{
   "Config1" : {
     "k1" : "v1",
     "k2" : "v2"
    ...........
   },
   "Config2" : {
     "k3" : "v3",
     "k4" : "v4"
   }
}
```

Using a singleton object to load the configuration as

```
services.Configure<Config1>(
                this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Config1)));
services.Configure<Config2>(
                this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Config2)));
```

And these objects are injected into calling function using constructor.

```
public claas C1
{
    public IOptionsMonitor<Config1> 

    public C1(IOptionsMonitor<Config2> config2, IOptionsMonitor<Config1> config1) 
    {
        this.config2 = config2;
        this.config1 = config1;
    }
}
```

Now we need to add a new configuration in the config file which should override some of the existing configs based on the payload from user.

So Config3 object will look like

```
"Config3" : {
  "userDefinedprop1" : {
     "Config2" : {
        "k4" : "v4"
     }
  },
  "userDefinedprop2" : {
     "Config1" : {
        "k1" : "v1"
     }
  }
   
}
```

I want to override some of the existing properties in config1 and config2 based on user input for each incoming request i.e during runtime. How should I approach this without breaking the existing functionality.

Comment: Have you packaged all these configurations into a single class? Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Chen No we have not packaged all the configurations into single class. It is packaged into multiple classes. So we will need to refresh the instance of affected classed at each and every request. I also would like to understand, how does it handle multiple requests at a time.

Comment: What is the pourpose of  "userDefinedprop2"? do you use this value somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you understand very well the [Configuration Provider model used in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). This Provider model allows you to add additional Providers to the "source of truth" for the application's Configuration, which is what your [Options Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0) are bound to.

Normally you can add static data as an "in memory collection" using an existing provider:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configuration =>
{
    configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" },
    });
});
```

But obviously this will not be updateable nor respond to any changes. ASP.NET Core doesn't have a Provider that does this, so you will need to write your own and add it to the application's Configuration.

In order to send updates to the Provider, we'll need an interface that can be injected into our Controllers:

```
public interface IUserConfigurationSource
{
    void Set(string key, string value);
}
```

And then the Provider itself can use the existing `ConfigurationProvider` base class to build off of:

```
public class UserConfigurationSource : ConfigurationProvider, IConfigurationSource, IUserConfigurationSource
{
    IConfigurationProvider IConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder) => this;

    public override void Set(string key, string value)
    {
        base.Set(key, value);
        OnReload();
    }
}
```

a couple notes: `IConfigurationSource` is the interface required to add a Provider to the application. the `ConfigurationProvider` base class already has a `Dictionary` we can use to store data in and a "reload token" we can use to trigger update notifications. however we need to override the `Set()` method to trigger the reload token so consumers will be notified.

and finally register your new provider in 2 places. 1 - add it as a Singleton to dependency injection so it can be consumed in Controllers:

```
var userConfigurationSource = new UserConfigurationSource();
services.AddSingleton<IUserConfigurationSource>(userConfigurationSource);
```

2 - add the instance as a Configuration "Source" to the Configuration subsystem:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configuration =>
{
    configuration.Add(userConfigurationSource);
});
```

Now you can inject `IUserConfigurationSource` into a Controller and update the data when the users change it:

```
public ActionResult Index(string count)
{
    _userConfigurationSource.Set("count", count);
    return View();
}
```

and your use of `IOptionsMonitor` will be able to access the updated values:

```
    config1.CurrentValue
```

however, note that if you have nested config keys, you'll need to use a colon (":") to list the full path of the config key in order for it to be bound to the Options correctly, so for your example config you might have:

```
    _userConfigurationSource.Set("Config3:userDefinedprop1:Config2:k4", "v4");
```

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your post. from your post, what I understood is it can update config when users change the configs. May be I was not clear. I already have configs defined in appsettings. According to new requirements I want to create a config3 in appsettings which will override some of the properties already present in config1 and config2 based on payload coming from user. So, I want to find a way which creates a config object so that it gets loaded on every request and not only at the start of program like we use services.addscoped<> for using some of the objects for the duration of a request.

Comment: Are you saying the "payload coming from user" changes on every request? If so, then you don't want to be trying to updating and using config objects, just have your controller map the values from the static config for the response. If the payload from the user only changes occasionally, then just use config3 values to update the config1 and config2 when that happens.

Comment: Makes sense. I found an approach which works better for our use and don't have to dynamically update configs anymore. Thanks .